# How do I tell Bazel about .netrc file?

Tags: bazel

I am new to Bazel and currently doing a POC on migrating a spring boot project from Maven to Bazel. I need to get dependencies from a third party artifactory like jfrog.

I have provided the credentials in .netrc file as below

```
machine https://xxx.jfrog.io/xxx/xxx-maven
login user.name@abc.com
password ****
```

But I am still getting unauthorized error when doing a Bazel build.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`machine` should just be the host name, and (I think) `login` doesn't need the email domain.

```
machine xxx.jfrog.io
login user.name
password ****
```

Comment: I have given them in this format too. But still does not seem to be working.